# I want to get ripped but don't know where to start. HELP!

Tags: bodybuilding, weight-gain, health, muscle-gain, endurance

I'm a smalls scrony 18 year old, and I want to get ripped! I have no self confidence issues, I just hate people taking advantage of me beacuse I'm a smaller build! I'm never hungry but I eat enough to maintain my weight.
I'm about 5'6" and weigh 125 lbs. I have know idea where to start gaining weight and turning it to muscle. I don't play sports so my endurance is not great either. I'd like to know how to build that as well. Help with daily diet and a 7 day work out plan that I can slowly increase difficulty would be nice too!
A specific question i have is: How many calories should I be eating everyday for weight gain? And does it matter if it's junk food? I heard that if your gaining weight it doesn't really matter, idk if that's true or not

Body:
Ht- 5"6'
Wt- 125 lbs.
Age- 18

Need help with:
Diet/how many calories daily do I need
Muscle building workout plan
And endurance training workout plan

I am hoping to workout daily

Comment: Use the site search function, all your questions have already been answered before.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a basic strength program like Stronglifts or Starting Strength.
And for your dietary needs: GOMAD. Gallon Of Milk A Day. That is ~2400kcal and ~120g of proteins.

Keep eating your normal amounts. I would still stay clear from too much junk food and focus on meats and veggies. 
A cheeseburger every once in a while is okay, just don't overdo it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your goals same as mine :) (i waked this path and still on it, look at my last question. Also i made many mistakes and here they are)

**1)** So, first of all - you don't need to workout every day.

Your body need time to regenerate all "damage" caused by working out.

I'd recommend you full body program 2-3 times per week for first two month.

Something like [this one](https://www.bodybuilding.com/content/the-ultimate-beginner-3-day-full-body-routine.html)

**2)** Watch your nutrition! You more need to care about what you are eating than about counting calories. Because of 200kcal u get by boiled chicken and 200kcal u get from chocolate bar impact different.
So simple rules:

- Wipe out sugar and all sweets/soda from your mind (but u can drink
  zero stuff). If you like your coffe/tea sweet - you can buy
  sweetener. Like aspartame, you can find it in every supermarket.
- Don't eat buns/bread (but in your case of underweight actually you can eat some dark bread I suppose)
- Reduce sauces.
- No aclohol/smoking.
- Try eat meat/fish more, but better boiled than fried.

**3)** You need to sleep minimum 8hrs.

**And last one** - try to walk by feet (not running, it's exausting and you can't run for like 40mins - 1hr straight) like around 6-12km per day. On your way to job. Or to the bus station (u can skip some just walking by feet).

**P.S.** 
I think you can ignore last advice because if your weight is so low you don't need that. I gain fat really fast thats why I trying to walk a lot, and it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is allowed but I bought a book called `Bigger, Leaner, Stronger` and I am currently following this program and I have seen good gains over the last 6 months. It's a great starting point and perfect for beginners because it teaches you the basics so you understand how training and nutrition affect your body and it also dispels a lot of myths that are banded around by so called "health/fitness/nutrition" gurus.

Check out some of his blog post's on [muscleforlife.com](https://www.muscleforlife.com/)

Also do a search on this site for `macro calculator` and you'll find a handy little calculator for working out your macro's.

Disclaimer: I am in no way affiliated with the author or muscleforlife.com. I just love the program and the knowledge he shares.

Oh and one last thing...your technique is by far more important than how heavy you can lift. Don't ever forget that :)

Comment: Book or program recommendations are acceptable as long as you explain why they would work for the querent, and you disclose any affiliation (in your case, none).

Answer (score -2):

First of all you need to know how much calories you need for doing your job. As a worker in a office you need like 2.2k calories.

I will do the calculation with my daily work and my added calories.

So I eat 2.2k calories to do my daily job but if I need to gain more I add like 700 more calories.

After that I eat like 3k calories a day.

If I do a heavy workout like legs or back I add more because a heavy workout burns like 600 calories(yeah I know someone will say more or less).

To gain muscles the muscle need protein.
I do it with 1kg=2g protein. In your case 56kg=112g 
Also keep the fat small to eat clean and train dirty

If you are new to training you should start with full-body training but with many rest days. Don`t go every day.
Later you can do a split.
I do a 3-split:

chest-tricpes
back-biceps
shoulder-leg-abs
and 2 rest days.

I hope this helps you